# Pandas split a column value to new column if list

Tags: python, pandas

I am still learning pandas and have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns as shown below:

```
actual label          pred label
     0                    -1
     0                    -1
     1           [1, 0.34496911461303364]
     1                    -1
```

What I would like to accomplish is if a value in 'pred label' is a list to take the first value in the list, in this case 1, and keep it in the column and then take the second value in the list and put it in its own column 'pred score'.

Comment: Is the "list" in your pred column actually a list, or a string representation of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not a great idea to store the DataFrame in this initial format in the first place if it can be avoided. Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'actual_label' : [0,0,1,1],
                  'pred_label' : [-1,-1, [1, 0.34496911461303364], -1]})

def split_label(v):
  if isinstance(v, list):
    return pd.Series(v, index = ['pred_label', 'pred_score'])
  return pd.Series(v, index = ['pred_label'])

new_pred = df.pred_label.apply(split_label)
df_new = pd.concat([df.actual_label, new_pred], axis=1)
```

The final output looks like this:

```
   actual_label  pred_label  pred_score
0             0          -1         NaN
1             0          -1         NaN
2             1           1    0.344969
3             1          -1         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to achieve it

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
  actual label  pred label
0            0          -1
1            0          -1
2            1  [1, 0.344]
3            1          -1
```

Using `apply` check if value is list `isinstance(x,list)` and take the value, and then `apply(pd.Series, 1)` to split as columns

```
In [75]: (df['pred label'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,list) else [x, np.nan])
                          .apply(pd.Series, 1))
Out[75]:
   0      1
0 -1    NaN
1 -1    NaN
2  1  0.344
3 -1    NaN
```

You could assign these two columns back to `df` with columns `['pred-lab', 'pred-score']`

```
In [76]: df[['pred-lab', 'pred-score']] = (df['pred label'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,list) else [x, np.nan])
                                                           .apply(pd.Series, 1))
```

Final `df` looks like

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
  actual label  pred label  pred-lab  pred-score
0            0          -1        -1         NaN
1            0          -1        -1         NaN
2            1  [1, 0.344]         1       0.344
3            1          -1        -1         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension together with `isinstance` to test if the object in `pred_label` is a list.

```
df['pred score'] = [c[1] if isinstance(c, list) else None for c in df['pred label']]
df['pred label'] = [c[0] if isinstance(c, list) else c for c in df['pred label']]
>>> df
   actual label  pred label  pred score
0             0          -1         NaN
1             0          -1         NaN
2             1           1    0.344969
3             1          -1         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach

```
d = {"actual label" : [0,0,1,1], "pred label" : [-1,-1,[1, 0.34496911461303364],-1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Assuming "pred label" is of type object and using boolean indexing.  Wondering if there's a better way to index into the list than what I'm doing here

```
filter = df["pred label"].str.len() == 2
df.loc[filter,"pred score"] = df[filter]["pred label"].tolist()[0][1]  
df.loc[filter,"pred label"] = df[filter]["pred label"].tolist()[0][0]
print(df)
   actual label pred label  pred score
0             0         -1         NaN
1             0         -1         NaN
2             1          1    0.344969
3             1         -1         NaN
```